# Cloudformation Name EC2 Instance with Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to give the EC2 instance created by my Cloudformation template a name.

```
  Tags:
    - Key: Name
    - Value: "blah"
```

Results in the error "Key not found in Tags property".  I see the key "Name" referenced in examples.  Why can't I use it?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML treats each hyphen as indicating a new element in a list, so your definition translates to JSON looking like this:

```
{
  "Tags": [
    {"Key": "Name" },
    {"Value": "blah" },
  ]
}
```

To fix, remove the hyphen before `Value`:

```
  Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: "blah"
```

Comment: The hyphen was the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that you did not declare the Name as a variable, so this should work:

```
Tags:
  - Key: "Name"
    Value: "blah"
```